# Emploi de "connaître bibliquement"

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques, religion

De nos jours, peut-on employer

> connaître qqn bibliquement

pour dire

> faire l'amour avec qqn

?

Comment: À qui ? Dans quel contexte ?

Comment: https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/connaitre première ligne : « I.− Vieilli ou littér. Connaître qqn ou qqc. Reconnaître. » — Origine littéraire : on peut imaginer un dialogue devant des enfants (quelques siècles passé) : « — Cher et noble ami, connaissez-vous la Marquise de … ? — Bien sûr, et depuis fort longtemps (*une pause et à voix basse*) … et même *bibliquement*. — (*sur le même ton*) Aahh ! Voilà qui vous honore … » et puis, la noblesse décimée, la séparation de l'Église …

Comment: … et de l'État consommée, la langue demeure, l'usage évolue, la discrétion originelle est discréditée par le peuple « — Tu connais la *prénom-féminin* — et même *mieux qu'çà* — [Suite censurée]. », seul l'adverbe à changé, dans cet emploi,  la légende du mot *connaître* est toujours reliée à l'élan vital. L'original monothéiste est toujours audible aujourd'hui, les pires athées connaissent la Genèse, ne serait-ce que pour la combattre, la dénigrer ou s'en moquer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est un euphémisme qui pouvait être utilisé jusqu'à il y a une cinquantaine d'années mais je ne suis pas sûr que les plus jeunes comprendraient tous ce que tu as voulu dire si tu l'employais aujourd'hui.

Comment: It's a bit old fashioned but I am 31 and I eared and have been using it for years. Based on the context, most slightly educated French speakers would get it

Answer (score 2):

Vous pouvez dire « connaitre qqn bibliquement » au lieu de « avoir des relations sexuelles avec qqn ». Cela semble indéniable d'après la référence suivante : [Expressions françaises](https://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-c/2678-connaitre-quelqu-un-bibliquement.html).

Je dois dire, cependant, que je partage les commentaires que l'on trouve dans cette référence, en particulier le second.

C'est une expression confirmée par [l'internaute](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/12507/connaitre-quelqu-un-bibliquement/).

Non seulement c'est une expression qui semble plutôt ampoulée selon l'appréciation trouvée dans la référence précédente, mais d'après la référence suivante, qui la situe mieux ([Tribune Apologétique](https://www.mots-surannes.fr/?p=30854)), elle serait aussi olé-olé, osée. Le côté « petit maitre » devient apparent dans les synonymes qui lui ont été trouvés : (parmi ses nombreux synonymes) «  présenter ses hommages à Madame la marquise  » « commenter les œuvres de Cujas », « prendre le café du pauvre ».
Personnellement je ne sais pas si oui ou non il faut voir et apprécier un euphémisme dans cette expression.